# How to insert image as a row in excel file using c#.net

Tags: c#

I have a query regarding export to excel functionality. In fact, I want to export the data into excel file with images. I am using c#.net. I'll appreciate your so kind of help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the Insert Method of the top-level picture manager:

```
Picture Insert(
    [In] string Filename, 
    [In, Optional] object Converter
);
```

Take a look at:

- [How to: Add Pictures and Word Art to Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178792%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Placing images in Excel using automation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8405/Placing-images-in-Excel-using-automation)

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: No but google has some examples